# How do i create different instances of a class using Enumerations as an identifier?

Tags: java

Hi im having problems with my game project because i require "extended" classes which have slightly different functions and creating an instance of Entity with just different names wont work properly since some classes have been extended.

Basically i have an entity class with different entities extending and implementing different classes, but i want to learn the best way of creating instances of each class just by using an enumeration. For example: new Entity(Enum.ZOMBIE) or new Entity(Enum.SPIDER)

Im doing it this way because my spawner's are designed to spawn in different types of creatures based on user input, and if i make an else if or switch method it will become very very long.

How would you solve this issue? Maybe inside my main class have a switch/case and return an instance of the modified class?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, i'm having trouble explaining how its supposed to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lookup table to store the name of the class with the way to create an instance of that class.

Assuming you have an `Entity` class and several classes that extends it: `Zombie`, `Spider`, `Hero`. You define an interface that creates an entity:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface EntityFactory {
    Entity create();
}
```

And a "table" to store the mapping from a name to instances of this interface:

```
Map<String, EntityFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you register your sub class factories:

```
factories.put("Zombie", Zombie::new);
factories.put("Spider", Spider::new);
factories.put("Hero", Hero::new);
```

And a util method that does the lookup and calling the appropriate factory:

```
Entity create(String name) {
    EntityFactory factory = factories.get(name);
    if (factory == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    return factory.create();
}
```

Now you can create entities from user input, as long as you register all entity classes:

```
Entity spider0 = create("Spider");
Entity hero0 = create("Hero");
```

Comment: Genius! Works amazingly :o

Answer (score 0):

Have a `Collection` of your instances and filter it according to user input :

```
List<Entity> availableEntities = new ArrayList<>();
availableEntities.add(new Entity("Zombie"));
///[...]

String userWants = "Zom";
Monster selectedEntity = availableEntities.stream()
                                           .filter(e-> e.getName().startsWith(userWants))
                                           .findFirst();
```

This solves the if/then/else/switch/case getting to long problem.

You could definitely use an `Enumeration` as an identifier, but it does not change much to the problem : instead of comparing `String`s as in my example, you'd compare instances of the enumeration instead (which is still cleaner).

Comment: I need to create a unique instance of each monster though, as they can be trained and such.

Comment: Well you need to handle them somehow anyway. You could have one variable by instance in your scope at all time, or you could put them in a nice collection

Comment: I took a look at how Minecraft do it, since they have a similar way to how i want to do it, they have the class inside the enum like this: SPIDER("name",Spider.class); and it looks like they have a giant method for checking if the Spider.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) based on the enum provided and if its true they just return a new Spider().. have you got a basic explanation on how this works or if its any good?

Comment: Eeeh, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't take advice from a project like Minecraft if you're doing a beginner's project. Still, I'll try to check out Minecraft's code and get back to you. Would you have a link to the source you're reading?

Comment: Ill pastebin it, ive used intelliJ to decompile CraftWorld, look for the spawnEntity method which takes a Location and Enum (EntityType), the method ends at "createEntity" which i kinda learnt how they do it.
//CraftWorld:
http://pastebin.com/i8WEnjdN
//EntityType:
http://pastebin.com/s3Xaa3ix

This isnt my code by the way, its owned by Bukkit i believe

Comment: Welp, I can't be bothered to retrieve the source code, but here are a few things : 1) `isAssignableFrom` basically is an instanceof check (behaves differently on `null` values). 2) from the enum instance you show, it looks like it's going to be used as a `Map<String, Class>`. 3) If you're going this way it looks like you need a specific subclass for each kind of `Entity` (which I thought you wanted to avoid). Having an `Enumeration` instance referring to these class is a bonus, but a `Map` or other `Collection` would do just as fine